# How to copy and paste range including format and column width

Tags: vba, excel

I am brand new in VBA and learning on my own. I came up with a code that works but I know there must be a more elegant way to write this without using the `Select` method.

```
wscount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Worksheets(1).Select
Range("B2:B100").Copy
Worksheets(wscount + 1).Select
Range("A1:A100").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I wish I could get the width of the column set in the code instead of copied from the source.

Also, is there a way to have the width of the column to change based on the "longest" text in one cell of the range?

Anyway, my two questions are:

1. how to write the above code without having to use `Select`, and
2. how to set the width of the column so I do not copy from the source.

Comment: [How to avoid using Select and Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6535336).

Comment: For setting column widths, try recording a macro using the Macro Recorder - while it is recording set the width of a column to, for instance 10, and then also autofit the width.  Stop the recorder and look at the macro generated - it will show two statements, e.g. `Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 10` and `Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are even more elegant ways yet, but with the information provided, this will do the trick.

```
Dim wscount as Integer
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb  = ActiveWorkbook
wscount = wb.Worksheets.Count

wb.Sheets.Add After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B100").Copy
wb.Worksheets(wscount + 1).Range("A1:A100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
wb.Worksheets(wscount + 1).range("a1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: Thanks you are awesome!